# With T-SQL how can I add html attributes to FOR XML PATH

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, for-xml-path

I have to use T-SQL (SQL Server) in a stored procedure to generate an html table from a `SELECT`. I'm not sure if/how I might be best able to add additional attributes to the basic html table attributes;

```
select 
    (select 'ID' as 'th' for xml path(''),  type),
    (select 'StartDate'   as 'th' for xml path(''), type),
    (select 'LPlace'  as 'th' for xml path(''), type)
union all 
select 
    (select p.[Id]     as 'td' for xml path(''), type),
    (select p.[Created]           as 'td' for xml path(''), type),
    (select p.[LPlace] as 'td' for xml path(''), type)
from [SourceTbl] p
for xml path('tr'), ROOT('table')
```

Results:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>StartDate</th>
    <th>LPlace</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2019-10-13T11:36:22.0050221</td>
    <td>K7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2019-03-10T13:12:07.1008696</td>
    <td>J6</td>
  </tr>
```

What I would like to add is things such as:

```
<table style=''font-family: Arial;font-size: 8pt;border: solid 1px #888;border-collapse: collapse;

<th style=''border: 1px solid #090F20;background-color: #0D417E;padding: 2px 0;color: #F8F8FF;font-size: 9pt;''>ID</th>
```

Thanks

Comment: Personally, if you're really "bothered" about the presentation, don't use SQL Server to create the HTML, and use a proper presentation layer.

Comment: How about simply adding a css stylesheet to the output? (If you don't want to go the presentation layer way.)

Comment: Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ee8006ee199235c0894fa92645645529   Rather than STYLE ... CLASS may be cleaner

Comment: @Larnu I know (I feel quite embarrassed - but I don't get to choose...)

Comment: Thanks @JohnCappelletti that's what I was looking for :)